# Getting error while servlet program HTTP Status 404 - /HelloWorldServlet/

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat7, eclipse-juno

**My Servlets program**

package com.srccodes.example;

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Helloworld
 */
@WebServlet("/Helloworld")
public class Helloworld extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Helloworld() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter printWriter  = response.getWriter();
        printWriter.println("<h1>Hello World!</h1>");
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

**update :**

**wec.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>HelloWorldServlet</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

while running above program on tomcat server am getting error 
error --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/655Ew.png.
how to resolve this problem,please try to suggest me,good answers will appriciate

Comment: what value you have for the display name in your web.xml : `<display-name>your_app_name</display-name>`

Comment: can you share your web.xml?

Comment: `<display-name>HelloWorldServlet</display-name>` this is the name

Comment: ya sure @Debojit Saikia

Comment: i'm update my question see the web.xml file @Debojit Saikia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their is nothing wrong in code you provided above.
your servlet name is 'Helloworld' and URL you are tryng is

```
http://localhost:8080/HelloworldServlet
```

if you want to run same servlet try

```
http://localhost:8080/HelloworldServlet/Helloworld
```

also Restart your server and check for URL.

Comment: while running tomcat it showing in browser only `http://localhost:8080/HelloworldServlet`.why?

Comment: you trying to run whole project not just servlet

Comment: as per your web.xml -> http://localhost:8080/HelloworldServlet means you are going for on of the welcome file

Comment: how to set whole project while running tomcat in eclipse?

Comment: Let me clear -- http://localhost:8080/HelloworldServlet/ is to run project with one of the welcome files from your 'WebContent' directory and http://localhost:8080/HelloworldServlet/Helloworld for specific servlet Helloworld

Comment: <servlet>
  <description>
  </description>
  <display-name>Helloworld</display-name>
  <servlet-name>Helloworld</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>com.srccodes.example.Helloworld</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Helloworld</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/Helloworld</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>                                                    add in your web.xml

Comment: how to set my project while running  now it gives http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldServlet/ .then how to set project  while running for giving http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldServlet/Helloworld? this

Comment: where to add that i mean where to add in between?

Comment: If your working with eclipse create servlet by their Add->Servlet step by step wizard it will automatically create mapping in web.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Remove "Servlet" from the url, something like `http://localhost:8080/Helloworld`

Comment: still same problem @pablo

Answer (score 0):

Is this class part of a WAR application? Try putting the WAR name between the port and HelloWorld.

Comment: where is the WAR file? where it is in my project

Comment: Try putting the project name then.